# Microsoft Graph api issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-teams

I have an issue with microsoft graph api when i try to display the total users in my organisation it only show the 100 users, but in my organisation nearly 150 users are there. May i know the reason behind these issue. Thanks advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask quality questions.

Comment: Please add your code what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to get `UserList` using `Microsoft Graph` its depends on your request with `query selection option`.

> You can use [`query parameters request`](http://query%20parameters) like  this
>   `graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=150`  to get your `150 users` by
>   request.

See the screen shot below:

[image]

For further details refer to [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter)
Hope that would help.